pronunciation of "vehicle"
The Oxford Advanced Learners' Dictionary gives both forms for vehicle:
/ˈviːəkl/,  /ˈviːhɪkl/
for American English.
Are the two pronunciations in free variation or can they be predicted based on sociolinguistic information?
For example, would college professors tend to have one pronunciation as opposed to truck drivers who might have the other?

I think you're being a bit presumptuous with "less educated", there. Bear in mind almost everyone aspirates the /h/ in trivially-derived vehicular. Note that the full OED gives both pronunciations (with/without /h/) under BrE and AmE.

whoever thought the question is "opinion-based" was only joking (I hope).

The edits to this question make it clear that it is not a matter of opinion; there is a true or false answer to the question of the degree of sociolinguistic variation here. Voting to reopen. That said, a good answer would need to cite reliable sources about such variation, not mere personal intuitions and tastes, and I have a feeling there isn't any actual data about this.

@SK: It was me, and I wasn't joking. I don't remember retracting my closevote (can a mod unilaterally do that on my behalf?), but I can't vtc again. I still think to the extent that it's not "a matter of opinion", it would be better asked on SO Linguistics.

Some native speakers pronounce the h in vehicle. That's from Pronunciation Pairs Teacher's Book, which specifically differentiates that "optional" (albeit relatively uncommon)  variation from the h in hour, which is never enunciated.

...on the other hand, If you want to sound smart, we vehemently say don't pronounce the h in vehicle (or in vehement, for that matter). That source points out that in Victorian times the opposite was true - it was considered "ignorant" not to enunciate the /h/ in vehicle back then. Of course, if the OP is a non-native speaker who just wants to avoid sounding uneducated today, the question belongs on English Language Learners.

On UK TV, there is a documentary crime series. When set in the southern states of America, I hear /ˈviː'hɪkju:l/. All pronunciations of this common word are probably regional more than a sociolect.

@Greybeard: I suspect it's an ELL question being asked by nns. There are many aspects of "Indian English" that are more aligned with Victorian English than with current "mainstream" English. But given IE has next to no "native" speakers, I don't think it's meaningful to ask whether you should downgrade your estimation of an IE speaker's social status depending on how faithfully they've retained the speech patterns of their great great grandfathers under the British Raj!

EXACTLY.  You can't imagine a cop at a traffic stop (especially in Texas) saying anything other than "step out of the VEE-HICKLE".  The college professor pronunciation doesn't quite convey the undertone of "boy, are you in trouble now" @greybeard

You might be interested in the following episode of Rob Words - there's a section on the silent h at time stamp 13:52. Is English just badly pronounced French?.

@FumbleFingers Your point about Indian English speakers has left me confused. I never mentioned Indian English, and emphasised that the pronunciation was not a sociolect.

@Greybeard: It kinda looks to me as though the OP wants it to be "a sociolect". Perhaps so he can label someone as "lower class" for using the less common pronunciation. Obviously you and I don't think it's a matter of "one pronunciation for educated people, and another for oiks". I was simply making the point that apparently many of the best style guides from the later 1800s were telling people they should enunciate the /h/ in vehicle. Indian English has definitely retained many features of Victorian English, which might explain why the question is being asked in the first place.

Since there's a lot of variation in how "h" is pronounced (words like "herb"/"herbicide", unstressed forms like "'im", in words that take "an" but the "h" is often sounded, and with general h-dropping as in Cockney) it wouldn't be surprising if it varies by dialect/region. (Caribbean English is known for widespread h-dropping for instance, and "veecle" is Jamaican Patwah for "vehicle".)

@Greybeard I've often noticed ideosyncratic vocabulary and pronunciation on American cop shows, too. "NYPD Blue" was notorious for it.

Am I wrong to suggest that different US accents or dialects might use anything from 'veecle' to 'vee-hicle' while most of us in the UK use 'veercle'?
